# Merge objects in javascript while ignoring property values that are undefined (jQuery.fn.extend behavior)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm looking for an implementation of `jQuery.fn.extend` in typescript/javascript. Specifically, I'm interested in the part where it ignores `undefined` values in the source object.

```
const obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: undefined
};

const obj2 = {
  a: undefined, // Should be ignored.
  b: 100
};

const merged = $.extend(obj1, obj2);

console.log(merged); // {a: 1, b: 100}
```

The structure of the objects to be merged is not necessarily well-known and one may contain more properties than the other.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/bentsai/3150936 what about starting from here? (or here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/438b1a3e8a52d3e4efd8aba45498477038849c97/src/core.js#L120)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could define a helper function that would create an object with the `undefined` properties removed:

```
const definedProps = obj => Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).filter(([k, v]) => v !== undefined)
);
```

And then the merge becomes:

```
const merged = Object.assign(obj1, definedProps(obj2));
```

```js
const obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: undefined
};

const obj2 = {
  a: undefined, // Should be ignored.
  b: 100
};

const definedProps = obj => Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).filter(([k, v]) => v !== undefined)
);
const merged = Object.assign(obj1, definedProps(obj2));

console.log(merged);
```

This solution uses [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) which is rather new, but it is easy to polyfill

```
Object.fromEntries = arr => Object.assign({}, ...arr.map( ([k, v]) => ({[k]: v}) ));
```